# Accessing a specific SKNode many times per second without impacting performance

Tags: arrays, swift, sprite-kit

I am working on a game that adopts Game Center to implement multiplayer functionalities.

Let's say we have on a scene about 50 `SKNode`'s and two players. `Player1` interacts with 25 of them and updates their positions; when this happens, the event is communicated to `Player2` with a packet containing all the vectors describing the current movement of the nodes.

Each of these nodes have a unique identifier, `uniqueID: UInt8`.

When `Player2` receives the packet containing all the vectors, the scene would have to update accordingly all the nodes depending on their unique identifiers, and here comes the problem.

To be able to access a specific node, given its identifier, it would be necessary to access the `SKScene`'s node tree, [search through it and retrieve the specific node by its assigned name or class identifier](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/sknode/1483060-childnode).

I would personally like not to do that; rather, I would like to access an `SKScene`'s node given its arbitrarily assigned identifier.

```
// Data from Multiplayer received handler
func dataReceived(data: Data) {
  let decodedData: UInt8 = ...
  let UID = decodedData << ...

  // Right now, I may only access the entity through its name
  let entity = scene.childNode(withName: String(UID))!
  // Modify the entity's properties according to the packet received

  // I would like to access the entity (or aka node) like so, without having to search through the children, single-access
  let entity = scene.getSpecificNode(withUID: UID)
}
```

Is it possible to do so? Thank you.

Comment: just use a dictionary

Comment: I thought about it, but what should the dictionary contain? A key containing the UID and... ? I would need a strong reference in memory to a node in the parent's children array, which continuously mutates; a dictionary with all the indices would be perfect, but these get updated every time a node is added/removed, and I can't be sure it doesn't happen any time else.

Comment: Not seeing the problem here, you are overthinking things.  You know when a sprite is added, you know when a sprite is removed. Add it and remove it at these time.